# Imagio ffmpeg libopenh264 warning: Slice count will be set automatically

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mp4, javax.imageio

I am trying to generate a simple mp4 using imageio, but I keep getting a warning on the slice count, which I have not been able to fix.
This code pops the warnings:

```
import imageio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

PNGfiles=[]

outfile="Test"

for ti in range(10):
    of=outfile+"_t_"+str(ti)+".png"
    PNGfiles.append(of)
    
    t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t+ti/np.pi)
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(t,s)
    plt.savefig(of)

with imageio.get_writer(outfile+".mp4",format="mp4", mode='I',) as writer:
    for filename in PNGfiles:
        image = imageio.imread(filename)
        writer.append_data(image)
```

And the output is:

```
[libopenh264 @ 0x562bbb818b40] Slice count will be set automatically
[libopenh264 @ 0x562bbb818b40] [OpenH264] this = 0x0x562bbba437d0, Warning:layerId(0) doesn't support profile(578), change to UNSPECIFIC profile
[libopenh264 @ 0x562bbb818b40] [OpenH264] this = 0x0x562bbba437d0, Warning:SliceArgumentValidationFixedSliceMode(), unsupported setting with Resolution and uiSliceNum combination under RC on! So uiSliceNum is changed to 6!
[libopenh264 @ 0x562bbb818b40] [OpenH264] this = 0x0x562bbba437d0, Warning:bEnableFrameSkip = 0,bitrate can't be controlled for RC_QUALITY_MODE,RC_BITRATE_MODE and RC_TIMESTAMP_MODE without enabling skip frame.
```

I know the warning is issued as soon as the first image is written to the file, that is, after the first iteration of the writing loop, but I have not found an option to pass so that the number of slices is set before the loop starts.

Thanks for your help.

I am running inside a conda environment reproducible with this yml file:
generated with this yml file:

```
name: py-env

channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults

dependencies:
  - matplotlib==3.5.2
  - imageio==2.9.0
  - imageio-ffmpeg==0.4.7
```

Comment: Could you add python + package versions? Running fine on 3.6.12 for me. Maybe consider calling `plt.clf()` one last time?

Comment: I am running python 3.10.5, imageio 2.9.0 and imageio-ffmpeg 0.4.7, inside a conda environment.

Comment: When I try to reproduce your example on a more recent version of imageio (2.21.1) I don't see this warning. I get a deprecation warning, but this is expected considering that you are using `imageio.imread` instead of explicitly specifying if you want the old (imageio.v2.imread) or new (imageio.v3.imread) `imread`. So my suggestion is to upgrade Imageio to something more recent and try again.